# ORA-02303 replacing object type used in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create an object in Oracle but I get the error

```
ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents.
```

I created the object `address_ot` to specify the address field in street or city or state or zip number.

The values like `first_name` and `last_name` can be retrieved but the `lv_address` is not retrievable.

```
create or replace type address_ot AS OBJECT
(street varchar2(100),city varchar2(50), state varchar(2),zip number(9));

create table exp_info
( first_name varchar2(50),
last_name varchar2(50),
birthdate DATE,
 address address_ot 
);

drop table exp_Info


DECLARE

lv_address address_ot; 

BEGIN
lv_address:= address_ot('California','Atlantia','AK',223);

insert into exp_info
values('Kara','Thrace','01-JAN-1980',lv_address);

END;
```

Checking the records:

```
SELECT  * from exp_info;
```

Comment: Using user-defined types as column data types is very cumbersome and also violates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form , so what exactly do you want to accomplish with that?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created the table that references the object type, you can't modify the type unless you first drop the table (or at least remove its object column):

```
create or replace type address_ot AS OBJECT
(street varchar2(100),city varchar2(50), state varchar(2));
/

Type ADDRESS_OT compiled

create table exp_info
( first_name varchar2(50),
last_name varchar2(50),
birthdate DATE,
 address address_ot 
);

Table EXP_INFO created.

create or replace type address_ot AS OBJECT
(street varchar2(100),city varchar2(50), state varchar(2),zip number(9));
/

Error starting at line : 12 in command -
create or replace type address_ot AS OBJECT
(street varchar2(100),city varchar2(50), state varchar(2),zip number(9));
Error report -
ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents
```

You get this error even with [force](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjmng.htm#ADOBJ7365), which works with type dependencies but not table dependencies:

```
create or replace type address_ot force AS OBJECT
(street varchar2(100),city varchar2(50), state varchar(2),zip number(9));
/

create or replace type address_ot force AS OBJECT
(street varchar2(100),city varchar2(50), state varchar(2),zip number(9));
Error report -
ORA-22866: cannot replace a type with table dependents
```

If you drop the table you can recreate the type and then recreate the table:

```
drop table exp_Info;

Table EXP_INFO dropped.

create or replace type address_ot AS OBJECT
(street varchar2(100),city varchar2(50), state varchar(2),zip number(9));
/

Type ADDRESS_OT compiled

create table exp_info
( first_name varchar2(50),
last_name varchar2(50),
birthdate DATE,
 address address_ot 
);

Table EXP_INFO created.
```

Then your block and query seem to work:

```
DECLARE

lv_address address_ot; 

BEGIN
lv_address:= address_ot('California','Atlantia','AK',223);

insert into exp_info
values('Kara','Thrace','01-JAN-1980',lv_address);

END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SELECT *from exp_info;

FIRST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------
LAST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------
BIRTHDATE
---------
ADDRESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Kara                                               
Thrace                                             01-JAN-80 
SCHEMA.ADDRESS_OT(California,Atlantia,AK,223)
```